# HTTP requests/responses analyser for Android

Tags: android, http-request

When using Firefox on my PC, for example, HTTP analysis is quite easy using for example the Net tab of Firebug. GETs, POSTs, etc., all there.

What would be the best technique to see the HTTP requests an Android app sends? Another app? Some kind of hack via Wi-Fi and a router or USB modem?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see outbound traffic from Android app to outside world, you can tap it if it passes through a local LAN. i.e. example if the HTTP request is going through 3G - that might not be possible,but through wifi, you can tap it at the LAN level. Basically, you can put any sniffer machine somewhere which runs something like wire-shark running on it.

If you are bothered about requests going to a particular application, server you can set the target URL as one of your local LAN server and tap it on the server side (using logs or sniffer).